How to parse and extract the tags containing ::marker?
So I'm trying to scrap some data from a website, and I want to extract the text inside the <li tag as shown below, the problem is they contain these ::markers that I understand are psudoelements, therefore they can't be parsed using BeautifulSoup?
<ul>
    <li>
        ::marker
        (text)
    </li>
    <li>
        ::marker
        (text)
    </li>
</ul>

This is what I tried, but it didn't returned other <li tags that don't contain the ::marker
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 


url = *the link of the website
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

reference = soup.find("li")
for element in reference:
    print(element.text())
    #output is only li elements without ::marker


can you share the html code that contains li with and without ::marker



      ::marker
      (text)
    
, this is the exact html code of the website
As there are multiple items it is probably an idea to use find_all and then iterate through those entries calling get_text on each one; something like:
list_items = soup.find_all("li")
for element in list_items:
    print(element.get_text())

You could add some extra code to check that find_all does actually return at least one element.

You can use a CSS selector to extract the text content of the li elements, excluding the ::marker pseudo-elements.
like this
li_elements = soup.select('li')
for li in li_elements:
    text = li.get_text(strip=True)
    print(text)

Note that this will extract the text content of all li elements, including those without the ::marker pseudo-element. If you only want to extract the text content of li elements that don't contain the ::marker pseudo-element, you can modify the CSS selector to exclude those elements:
li_elements = soup.select('li:not(::marker)')

This will select only the li elements that don't contain the ::marker pseudo-element.

It still does not work, I read somewhere that this is not supported in BeautifulSoup? Should I use another library or something

So then use some other library like PyQuery which allow you to manipulate CSS elements and extract data or you should use Playwright or Puppeteer which can execute JavaScript and render the page like a browser, allowing you to access the generated content, including pseudo-elements.
This will launch a Chromium browser instance, navigate to the URL, and extract the text content of all li elements, including those with pseudo-elements like ::marker.
here is some example from net

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
browser = p.chromium.launch()
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()
page.goto(url)
li_elements = page.query_selector_all('li')
for li in li_elements:
    text = li.inner_text()
    print(text)

